# Can´t draw plain amp with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm trying to use the package circuitikz, and I need to draw a plain amp, I'm traying to do this as the manual says but it keep throwing this error message

```
"I don´t know the '/tikz/plain amp' and i'm going to ignore it "
```

this is the code that i'm using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (5,5) node[plain amp](amp){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

hope you can help me!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your example works fine for me, perhaps you have an older version of `circuitikz`. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{article}` and look in the log-file after compilation, at the end should be a list of all packages and their versions. I have v. 0.2.4 of `circuitikz`.

Comment: It works here. Probably different circuitikz version. If you search for the string `CircuiTikz` in your `.log` file, you can read the version. Mine is `Package: circuitikz 2009/11/18 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.2.4`.

Comment: you were right!, i had an older version, but i updated it and now a have this error message
    "I can´t find file 'circuitikz.code.tex'. \input circuitikz.code.tex

does anyone now why is this happening?

Comment: Pablo, for @JLDiaz and Torbjorn to get a notification you need to link their names as I did with the @. JLDiaz will see this message, and you might want to alert Torbjorn as well (I think only one name can be linked in each comment)

Comment: How did you update it, by just downloading the newest `circuitikz.sty` from CTAN and replacing the old one? While I have never used the package, it seems there is an additional file that is missing, so perhaps you can just download that one as well, and place it in the same folder. In general though, it is better to update using the package manager of your (La)TeX distribution. E.g. the Update manager of MikTeX (found in the Start menu). For TeX Live there is a command line utility, `tlmgr update --self --all` will update all packages. (ctd.)

Comment: Note however that the TeX Live found in Ubuntu's repositories does not have this utility, in which case a manual install is required, I think. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution for more about the general issue.